# Need to have users in multiple protection groups

Tags: minix, multiple-users

I have a project that I'm doing for my OS class and there's a part of it that has me a bit stumped:

> Have at least 3 different ordinary users on your system, and at least three different protection groups, with each protection group consisting of two of the users and no two groups the same (e.g., users A, B, and C, with protection groups X={A,B}, Y={B,C}, and Z={C,A}).

Here's what I tried (groups X, Y, and Z have already been created):

```
# user add -m -g X A
# user add -m -g X B
# user add -m -g Y B
```

The last command gives me the following:
 `user: Can't add user 'B': 'B' is already a user`

**EDIT:** I was able to figure it out on my own. For those interested, I used the "usermod -G" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out on my own. For those interested, I used the `usermod -G` command.